# How to get update selecting text by keys

Tags: jquery

I am updating the text, according to the user select the text. it works fine. I added a `keyup` to deduct the selection made or extended by `arrow` keys. But it is not working after i added `keyup` with my existing events.

```
$('#tenderContent').on('mouseup, mousemove, keyup', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //not working after adding keyup.
        if ($.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
            $('#text').text(window.getSelection().toString());
        }

    });

    $('#tenderContent').on('mousemove', '.tenderdocument', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (!$.trim(window.getSelection().toString()).length) {
             $('#text').empty();
        }
    });
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mx09jcay/7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to separate them by a comma, just put space between them to use multiple events:

Replace this:

```
.on('mouseup, mousemove, keyup'
```

With this:

```
.on('mouseup mousemove keyup'
```